# Android Bitmap Decode and Arrays

Tags: android, arrays, canvas, bitmap

The following code is what I have pieced together from articles on here but im really stumped what next to try

```
ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArray = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++){
            bitmapArray.add(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/" + Global.svar7));
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapArray[i], 0, 0, null);
 }
```

Basically I am trying to draw 3 bitmaps to the canvas one below the other within a loop

This is the nearest I have got with just one error on the `Canvas.drawBitmap` line saying that `bitmapArray[i]` has the error

> The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList

I have search this error on here and can only find examples that include strings and setting controls

Any ideas? can you please point me in the right direction?

Your help is Greatly appreciated

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access items in an ArrayList, use [ArrayList.get()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)):

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapArray.get(i-1), 0, 0, null);
```

You'll need to subtract 1 from the index because you are starting your loop from 1 not 0.

Comment: Thank you so much changed to canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapArray.get(i-1),null, new Rect(a,basenum2,a+200,basenum3), null); and it works a treat

Answer (score 1):

You try to use ArrayList as Array. replace `bitmapArray[i]` with `bitmapArray.get(i)`.

Also you should consider that array and List indexes start from 0, not from 1, so you need also to replace  `for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++){` with  `for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){`